# Getting error during late initialisation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flags

I am calling form below for add and edit operations.When clicked on edit button I have to get details of particular document based on its unique Id, so when clicked on edit I am calling API in initState() but when clicked on add button I am facing an issue like futureDocuments is not initialised, I cannot initialise it to null also, how to resolve this?
I am also getting an error like dId is not initialised while cliked on add document button
please guide me towards both the initializations

```
class DocumentForm extends StatefulWidget {
  bool update;
  final String userName;

  //final String createdBY;

  DocumentForm(this.userName, this.update);
  @override
  State createState() {
    return _DocumentFormState(this.userName, this.update);
  }
}
// AddAppointmentState<AddDocument> createState() => _AddDocumentState();

class _DocumentFormState extends State<DocumentForm> {
  final String userName;
  String playerId = '';
  bool update;

  //final String createdBY;

  _DocumentFormState(this.userName, this.update);
  late final String date1;

  late String datainput;

  final List<String> items1 = ["Open", "Closed", "Cancel", "Submitted"];
  String? selectedItem;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController docIdController = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController docTitleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController tokenNoController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController cityController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController docStatusController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController docTypeController = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController partyNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController durationController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController pinCodeController = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController rentDescController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController startDateController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController endDateController = TextEditingController();
  late TextEditingController docstatusController = TextEditingController();

  late String docType = docTypeController.text;
  late final String createdBY;

  final List<String> items = [
    "Residential",
    "Commercial",
  ];
  String? selectedValue;

  late Future<Document>? futureDocuments;
 @override
  void initState() {
    this.update == true
        ? futureDocuments = DocumentController.fetchDocumentsByID(this.dId)
        : futureDocuments = null;
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();
    // initPlatformState();
    // initPlatformStateApt();
    init();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    docStatusController.dispose();
    docTypeController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future init() async {
    // initPlatformState();
  }

  @override
  Future<Document>? _futureDocument;
 body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            //width: width * 1,
            //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
            child: (_futureDocument == null)
                ? buildColumn(update)
                : buildFutureBuilder(),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(10))),
          ),
        ),
      ),
 Form buildColumn(bool update) {
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: FutureBuilder<Document>(
          future: futureDocuments,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                createdBY = snapshot.data!.createdBy;
                this.dId = snapshot.data!.docId;

                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    // SizedBox(
                    //   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
                    //   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 8,
                    // child:
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
                        // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          // minLines: 1,
                          // maxLines: 5,

                          // textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,

                          // //autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            //  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(100),
                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                RegExp("[ ',-/ a-z A-Z á-ú Á-Ú 0-9]")),
                          ],

                          controller: this.update == true
                              ? docTitleController = TextEditingController(
                                  text: '${snapshot.data!.docTitle}')
                              : docTitleController,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                          // keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(30),
                              )),
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                              ),
                              labelText: 'Document Title',
                              hintText: 'Document title required'),

                          // validator: ,
                          validator: MultiValidator(
                              [RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Required*')]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                              ),
                              // minLines: 1,
                              // maxLines: 2,
                              inputFormatters: [
                                FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                                LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(14)
                              ],
                              // //autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                              controller: this.update == true
                                  ? tokenNoController = TextEditingController(
                                      text: '${snapshot.data!.tokenNo}')
                                  : tokenNoController,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
                                  counterText: "",
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                                  ),
                                  focusColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 87,
                                      156), //Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 153, 33),
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                  ),
                                  labelText: 'Token No',
                                  hintText: 'Token no required'),
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'Please enter token No';
                                } else if (value.length < 14) {
                                  return 'Please enter 14 digits number';
                                }
                                return null;
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.01,
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                              // minLines: 1,
                              // maxLines: 2,
                              //autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                              inputFormatters: [
                                FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                                LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2)
                              ],
                              controller: this.update == true
                                  ? durationController = TextEditingController(
                                      text: '${snapshot.data!.duration}')
                                  : durationController,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(30))),
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                  ),
                                  labelText: 'Duration(M)',
                                  hintText: 'Duration required'),
                              validator: MultiValidator(
                                [RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Required*')],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                              //  //autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                              //FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[- 0-9]")),
                              inputFormatters: [
                                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                    RegExp("[- 0-9]")),
                                LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)
                              ],
                              controller: this.update == true
                                  ? startDateController = TextEditingController(
                                      text: '${snapshot.data!.startDate}')
                                  : startDateController,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                ),
                                labelText: 'Start Date',
                                hintText: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                              ),
                              onTap: () async {
                                DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                                  context: context,
                                  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                  firstDate: DateTime(
                                      1991), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
                                  lastDate: DateTime(2101),
                                  // onConfirm:widget.onChanged,
                                ).then((pickedDate) {
                                  if (pickedDate != null) {
                                    // print(
                                    // pickedDate); //pickedDate output format => 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000
                                    String formattedDate =
                                        DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
                                            .format(pickedDate);

                                    print(formattedDate);

                                    setState(() {
                                      startDateController.text = formattedDate;
                                      //set output date to TextField value.
                                    });
                                    print(startDateController.text);
                                  } else {
                                    print("Date is not selected");
                                  }
                                });
                                final int dur =
                                    int.parse(durationController.text);
                                var stDate =
                                    DateTime.parse(startDateController.text);

                                var jiffy = Jiffy(stDate).add(
                                  months: dur,
                                  days: -1,
                                  // days: 1095,
                                );
                                DateTime d = jiffy.dateTime;
                                String s = jiffy.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
                                setState(() {
                                  endDateController.text = s.toString();
                                });
                              },

                              validator: MultiValidator(
                                  [RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Required*')]),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            height: 30,
                            width: 150,
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // ******Add new document **********///////
                                  formKey.currentState?.validate();
                                  final isValidForm =
                                      formKey.currentState!.validate();
                                  if (isValidForm && (update == false)) {
                                    final String docTitle =
                                        docTitleController.text;
                                    final int tokenNo =
                                        int.parse(tokenNoController.text)
                                            .toInt();
                                    //final String tokenNo = tokenNoController.text;
                                    final String partyName =
                                        partyNameController.text;

                                    // addStatus(selectedItem!);
                                    final String docType =
                                        selectedValue.toString();
                                    final String docStatus =
                                        selectedItem.toString();

                                    final String address =
                                        addressController.text;

                                    final String city = cityController.text;

                                    final String rentDesc =
                                        rentDescController.text;
                                    final String pinCode =
                                        pinCodeController.text;
                                    final String duration =
                                        durationController.text;

                                    final String startDate =
                                        startDateController.text;
                                    final String endDate =
                                        endDateController.text;
                                    final String createdBy = this.userName;
                                    print('Username :${createdBy}');
                                    final String updatedBy = '';

                                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                                DocumentPage(
                                                  this.userName,
                                                )));

                                    setState(() {
                                      _futureDocument = createDocument(
                                        // docId,
                                        docTitle,
                                        tokenNo,
                                        partyName,
                                        docType,
                                        address,
                                        city,
                                        pinCode,
                                        duration,
                                        rentDesc,
                                        docStatus,
                                        startDate,
                                        endDate,
                                        createdBy,
                                        updatedBy,
                                        //  createdAt,
                                      );
                                    });
                                    // }
                                    //}
                                  }

                                  ///*****************/

                                  //****Edit document ******/
                                  else if (isValidForm && update == true) {
                                    final int docid = snapshot.data!.docId;

                                    final String docTitle =
                                        docTitleController.text;
                                    final int tokenNo =
                                        int.parse(tokenNoController.text)
                                            .toInt();
                                    final String partyName =
                                        partyNameController.text;
                                    final String docType =
                                        docTypeController.text;
                                    final String city = cityController.text;
                                    final String address =
                                        addressController.text;
                                    final String pinCode =
                                        pinCodeController.text;

                                    final String duration =
                                        durationController.text;

                                    final String rentDesc =
                                        rentDescController.text;
                                    final String docStatus =
                                        docstatusController.text;

                                    final String startDate =
                                        startDateController.text;
                                    final String endDate =
                                        endDateController.text;
                                    final String createdBy = this.createdBY;
                                    final String updatedBy = this.userName;
                                    print(
                                        'the user name from doc edit page ${this.userName}');

                                    setState(() {
                                      futureDocuments = updateDocument(
                                          docid,
                                          docTitle,
                                          tokenNo,
                                          partyName,
                                          docType,
                                          address,
                                          city,
                                          pinCode,
                                          duration,
                                          rentDesc,
                                          docStatus,
                                          startDate,
                                          endDate,
                                          createdBy,
                                          updatedBy);

                                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                                  DocumentsDetails(
                                                    docid,
                                                    this.userName,
                                                  )));
                                    });
                                  }
                                  ;
                                },
                                child: const Text("Save"),
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                      Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 153, 33),
                                      //Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 153, 33)
                                    ),
                                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                        RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                        //side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
                                      ),
                                    )))),
   ],
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }
            }
            return Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator());
          }),
    );
    //])
    //);
  }

  FutureBuilder<Document> buildFutureBuilder() {
    return FutureBuilder<Document>(
      future: _futureDocument,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(snapshot.data!.docTitle);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        }

        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you share your full code with main method.

Comment: please put the onclick method of edit button its difficult to find the method of click

Comment: @Rishabh Agrawal
Cannot share full code here in question as its too much longer and exceeding the limits

Answer (score 0):

You can remove **late** since it's already nullable. You have to also update the state after assigning it to **futureDocuments**.

Answer (score 0):

Change `late` to `nullable` values using `?` operator. i.e

Change from

```
late final String date1;
late String datainput;
```

to

```
final String? date1;
String? datainput;
```

Now you can assign `null` to `date1` and `datainput`!